# IE8 bug? div with height, position:absolute, and opacity doesn't display correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a CSS problem in IE8. The full height of .test_div is not showing when I add an opacity in #header. But the full height of .test_div will show when I remove the opacity.

This works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE8. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!! :)

The code is also here:
http://jsfiddle.net/VPkXu/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="test_div">test square</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    background: #888;
    /* remove the lines below, the full height of .test_div will be visible (IE8)*/
    opacity: 0.7;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)"; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
}

.test_div {
    background:#CCC;
    height:500px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: looks fine in ie8 compatibility from IE9 ..

Comment: Keep in mind that IE9 supports CSS Opacity, while in IE8 you're stuck with the very buggy Alpha DXFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way would be to take out this div from inside of #header

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div class="test_div">test square</div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

and apply position and z-index to .test_div

```
.test_div {
    z-index: 11;
    position:absolute;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/7aXJD/